# How to test the convergency of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to test that the following series is convergent

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+1}+\frac{1}{2^3+1}+\dots$$

attempt:

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{2^n+1}{2^{n+1}+1}$$
Then how to get the value. Is it $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{2^n+1}{2^{n+1}+1}$$
divide the Numerator and denominator by $2^{n+1}$
$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{\frac{2^n}{2^{n}.2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{1/2+0}{1+0}=0.5$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the comparison test here, since 
$$\frac 1{2^n+1}<\frac 1{2^n}.$$

Since,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{2^n}$$
is a geometric series, with $1/2<1$, it converges, so the given series converges.

Answer (score 2):

It's $1/2$, since $\frac{2^n+1}{2^{n+1}+1} = \frac{1+1/2^n}{2+1/2^n}$ and $1/2^n$ converges to zero.